# Angular combine 2 promises to 1 promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

In my app I am trying to implement a `loadAll` method.

What needs to be done, is to call 2 http methods to load the data.

These 2 methods return promises.

When I try to combine them to one promise, I get an error.

```
  loadAll() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(
        this.getAllItem1ToConnect(),
          this.getAllItem2ToConnect();
      );
    }
    );
  }
```

I realize this is wrong, how do I implement this?

getAllItem1ToConnect method:

```
  getAllItem1ToConnect() {
    return this.http.get<Item1[]>(this.path + '/item').toPromise().then((res: Item1[]) => {
      this.items1 = res;
    });
  }
```

How do I combine `getAllItem1ToConnect` and `getAllItem2ToConnect` to 1 promise?

Comment: I'd suggest you skip `toPromise()` and learn how to use observables instead

Comment: @ShamPooSham Thanks, but I need it to be specifically a promise... Don't worry, I'm using observables everywhere else :)

Comment: That's good :) I see it everywhere, people using toPromise because they're afraid of observables. But yes, sometimes you just have to use promises

Comment: If you are in the beginning of your project I'd strongly recommend sticking with rxjs. You have to have it anyways so you may as well take advantage of its benefits and you don't have to go back and forth with promises.

Comment: @bryjohns Thanks, this is actually for a special feature at the end of the project...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all`. This takes an array of `Promises` and returns a single `Promise`.

```js
function func1() {
  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res('from func1'), 1000);
  });
}

function func2() {
  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res('from func2'), 1000);
  });
}

Promise.all([func1(), func2()]).then( res => console.log(res));
```

So, in your case, you want:

```
const promise = Promise.all([
  this.getAllItem1ToConnect(),
  this.getAllItem2ToConnect()
]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed... works perfectly